# How to find records between date range on per day basis

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to fetch records from mongoDB between two date and time. But I want record on per day basis. When I match the record on date range with time Like my date range from 2016-08-01 08:00:00 to 2016-08-15 20:00:00. So I want record on behalf of per day records for example

```
from 2016-08-01 08:00:00 to 2016-08-01 20:00:00
from 2016-08-02 08:00:00 to 2016-08-02 20:00:00
.
.
.
.
from 2016-08-15 08:00:00 to 2016-08-15 20:00:00
```

Please suggest how to find this solution.

Comment: Could you also add the db structure and some sample records for a better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should store timestamp if you want to search on time as well and then use $gte and $lte opertaors:

```
db.collectionName.find({datestart:{$gte: 'start_time_of_day', $lt: 'end_time_of_day'}});
```

Another solution If you want to search on date like you have stored is:

```
db.collectionName.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2016-05-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2016-05-11T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!